# Script# Wrap WebGL?

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio, webgl, script#

How would one go about wrapping WebGL in Script#.

I tried to add stuff to the source code but get compile errors I don't understand.

```
[ScriptIgnoreNamespace]
    [ScriptImport]
    [ScriptName("webGL")]
    public sealed class WebGL
    {
        [ScriptName("fooGL")]
        public void Foo(string test)
        {

        }
    }
```

> Error 1   The base class or interface 'System.FormatException' in
>   assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' referenced by type
>   'System.UriFormatException' could not be
>   resolved  c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll    Web

Or is there a way better way to add WebGL support as a lib rather then adding it directly to the main source?

**EDIT: Looks like that compiler error was coming from VS from auto adding System.dll to the project and it shouldn't be.  After removing it now compiles.  So now the question is what is the best way to wrap a javaScript API in Script# ??**

Comment: GLSL, which is what WebGL uses, is not JavaScript.  Script# appears to only generated JavaScript.  I'm not quite sure why you would think this would work.

Comment: "GLSL" is a Shader lang, not a GLES2 lang.  WebGL controls GLES2 via javaScript, it does not control GLSL, GLES2 is whats responsible for GLSL...

Comment: that's like the difference between a Subaru Forester and a Subaru Outback. They're both Subaru.  Even the WebGL specification distinguishes this. "A shader referencing state variables or functions that are available in other versions of GLSL, such as that found in versions of OpenGL for the desktop, must not be allowed to load."  If we want to be pedantic, the shaders in WebGL is not GLES2, it's *mostly* a subset. See => https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/#6

Comment: (Although, strictly speaking about the shader language itself, the only real obvious difference I see is " identifiers starting with 'webgl_' and '_webgl_' are reserved for use by WebGL.".)

Comment: Either way GLSL is irrelevant to the question, as you don't code GLSL in JavaScript, you code GLES2(aka WebGL) in JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, after a re-read, WebGL is barely relevant to what you apparently desire to be answered... you are asking how to generate, as part of the code generated from Script#, any objects, method calls, etc, to ANY external api.  Is this question similar?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859869/how-to-import-properties-of-an-external-api-into-script

Comment: Hmm maybe I think it may be tnx, i'll take a look.

Comment: NP, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the S# source on github for how wrappers are written. They're simply classes tagged with ScriptImport attribute and the internal methods/properties have empty values/bodies.

Look at the source [here](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp/tree/cc/src/Libraries/Web/Html).